# How to use ref to run function from parent in multiple child components using vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to run a function in each of my child components using ref, however it seems to do nothing when i run it.

Each of the child components is based upon data from an API. When call `updateUserDataDB` 
it fetches said api, uploads to firestore and changes it owns variables. However currently this has to be done via a button on each child component. I would like to setup a button on the parent component to run this function on all children. For this i have looked at [this article](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/vuejs/parent-call-child-component-method) which was linked in another question, however to no avail. Perhapds is has something to do with using the same ref in all children? Any help or tips is appreciated.
My code looks as such 
*App.vue (parent)*

```
<template>
<body>
  <button class="btn-right"  @click ="updateUserDataDB"> Update all PlayerBoxes</button>
  <p v-for="country in countries" :key="country" >
    <PlayerBox :players="country :ref="'refresh_db' + country"/>
  </p>
</body>
</template>
<script>

import { query, collection, getDocs, orderBy, setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore"
import db from './firebase/init.js'
import PlayerBox from './components/PlayerBox.vue'
import{ref} from "vue"

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { PlayerBox},
  data() {
    return {
      players: [],
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getPlayerFirestore()
    
  },
  methods: {
    updateUserDataDB(){
      console.log("clicked")
      this.$refs.refresh_db.updateUserDataDB()
    },
    async getPlayerFirestore() {
      // query to get all docs in 'users' collection
      const q = query(collection(db, 'users'), orderBy('elo', 'desc'));
      const querySnap = await getDocs(q);
      // add each doc to 'players' array 
      querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
        this.players.push(doc.data())        
      })
    },
</script>
```

*PlayerBox.vue (child)*

```
<template>
...
</template>
<cript>

import { getDoc, updateDoc , doc} from "firebase/firestore"
import db from '../firebase/init.js'
import {ref} from "vue";

export default ({
    props:["players"],
    data(){
    ...},
    methods: {
        async updateChampionStats(){
           ...
        },
        async updateUserDataDB() {
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: At first glance I would redirect you to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228409/how-to-get-refs-array-in-vue-js) on how to get an array of refs since here, at best you'd have the last element of countries set as the reference, meaning that a ref should be used like an ID, you can't have two elements for the same name

Comment: @savageGoat thanks for the response. I edited to question to contain a ref to in the for loop which should now be unique for each component, however i still do not understand how i can create a button to call the function "updateUserDataDB" in each component. Since every ref is now unique, would i need to add a for loop in the App.vue updateUserDataDB function to cycle through each ref and call said function ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it needs, note that you can filter your refs too if you have other refs in your page, `Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach(key => if (key.indexOf("refresh_db") > -1) { this.$refs[key].updateUserDataDB() })`

Comment: I tired adding the function which you linked to the updateUserDataDB function in App.vue, however it returns an error. With my understanding of the syntax for the function you sent, i cannot decypher it. Help is appreciated. The function looks as follows ```updateUserDataDB(){
      Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach(key =>{ 
        if (key.indexOf("refresh_db") > -1) { this.$refs[key].updateUserDataDB() }})
    },```
I get the following error  https://prnt.sc/ySZmBlxhJsEW when activating the button running the function

Comment: My bad, I missed a small yet important step: Refs should be set to the element, not its parent, you are trying to trigger `PlayerBox`'s function, not its parent `p`

Comment: I have now changed the code to send the ref with the PlayerBox instead of in the tag ```p``` however i am still getting the same error as in the earlier posted picture.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Vue3 ? Vue structures vary depending on the version, on vue3+ I believe it's `this.$refs[ myRefKey ].value.method`, and IIRC Vue4 components are completly scoped so you need variable update to trigger `watch` in the child to process an action

Comment: I have now made the function ```updateUserDataDB(){    
      console.log("test")   
      Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach(key =>{
        if (key.indexOf("refresh_db") > -1) { 
          this.$refs["refresh_db"].value.updateUserDataDB() 
        }
      })     
    }``` 
however now im getting an error with the .value part https://prnt.sc/ATwrrTzVztLt
Perhaps there is an easier way of communication a function to be run at every child?
I see many people reccommend props too, however im only using this to pass the information for the child component at the current time